# My .NET Framework WPF App doesn't see my .NET Standard Library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-standard

I am trying to follow up with a tutorial and I did everything perfectly, I checked 3 times. I am new to this.

This is the class, **this was a .NET Core library** and I migrated it by simply editing the `.csproj` file:

```
namespace WiredBrainCoffee.Simulator
{
    public class CoffeeMachine
    {
        public int CounterCappuccino { get; private set; }

        public void MakeCappuccino()
        {
            CounterCappuccino++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the .NET Framework WPF application code which contains a simple button and a text box that updates and adds one every time I press the button.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _coffeMachine = new CoffeMachine();
            txtCappucinoCounter.Text = _coffeMachine.CounterCappuccino.ToString();
        }

        private void ButtonMakeCappuccinoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _coffeMachine.MakeCappuccino();
            txtCappucinoCounter.Text = _coffeeMachine.CounterCappuccino.ToString();
        }
```

The problem is it is not working. *_coffeMachine* has a red underline every where and I can't generate the `using WiredBrainCoffee.Simulator` automatically so I tried manually but it is not working either.

Comment: _coffeemachine needs to be declared as a class variable so you can access it in any of the methods of the class.

Comment: That's what the tutorial is about, but even tho I create another, it is the same thing. isn't it?

Comment: Are you sure it is a ".NET Core library"? https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project, Add -> Reference, select the other Project.

Ensure the class you want to use is public (its internal by default).

You also need to define the type of _coffeMaker. In your case it needs to be a class-variable

It should work then

Comment: Mark this as answer please then